# movie-trailer npm isn't working properly in my netflix clone project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, fetch

I've made a netflix clone using React.js, firebase, and have used TMDB api for movie database.
I've also used react-youtube and movie-trailer npm.
So it has this feature that every time I click on any movie poster, it's trailer must be played.
But for most of the movies, trailer doesn't shows up.

This is the error that I face -
movie-trailer: No TMDB Movie found with the current search terms, try searching https://www.themoviedb.org/search?query=Luis%20Miguel%3A%20The%20Series
TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
at Row.js:37

'[This is the screenshot of errors I am facing on clicking maximum of movies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecpf2.jpg)'

I'm sharing the link of my github repo and deployed website as well for reference -

github - https://github.com/IshitaSharma3101/netflix-clone

website - https://netflix-clone-afb8b.web.app/

Row component code-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import YouTube from "react-youtube";
import axios from "./axios";
import "./Row.css";
import movieTrailer from "movie-trailer"

const base_url = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/";

function Row({ title, fetchURL, isLargeRow }) {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [trailerURL, setTrailerURL] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const request = await axios.get(fetchURL);
      console.log(request.data.results);
      setMovies(request.data.results);
      return request;
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [fetchURL]);

  const opts = {
    height: "390",
    width: "100%",
    playerVars: {
      autoplay: 1,
    },
  };

  const handleClick = (movie) => {
    if (trailerURL) {
      setTrailerURL("");
    } else {
      movieTrailer(movie?.name || movie?.title || movie?.original_title || "")
        .then((url) => {
          const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(new URL(url).search);
          setTrailerURL(urlParams.get("v"));
        })
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='row'>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <div className='row__posters'>
        {movies.map((movie) => (
          <img
            key={movie.id}
            onClick={() => handleClick(movie)}
            className={`row__poster ${isLargeRow && "row__posterLarge"}`}
            src={`${base_url}${
              isLargeRow ? movie.poster_path : movie.backdrop_path
            }`}
            alt={movie.name}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
      {trailerURL && <YouTube videoId={trailerURL} opts={opts} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Row;
```

Comment: it looks like you might be rate limited.

Comment: Rate as in? Like in what way?

Comment: Hi, I'm the developer of `movie-trailer`. As the name suggests, `movie-trailer` only works for movies, not TV shows. There's an issue open on Github about it: https://github.com/lacymorrow/movie-trailer/issues/5. 

This is due to a limitation with the TMDB API unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Use this instead.

```
      movieTrailer(null ,{ tmdbId: movie.id })
                   .then((url)=>{
                     console.log("url is "+url);
                     const urlParams=new URLSearchParams(new URL(url).search);
                     console.log("urlParamsn"+urlParams);
                     setTrailerUrl(urlParams.get("v"));
                   })
                   .catch((error)=> console.log(error));
    }
 }
```

With this you can search for the movie with the tmdb id.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you are following the Clever Qazi tutorial as I'm doing. I think there is basically no solution for this problem. I also try to get the trailer of the movies by the ID that TMDB gives for every film but this method definitely doesn't work for mine. My conclusion is that movie-trailer is not working for certain kind of film or series...

You can prove yourself my conlclusion by typing on a terminal `npx movie-trailer Cobra Kai`
which is the command that allow you to use this package. Cobra Kai is a well know series but this "tool" doesn't find any trailer for it.

Comment: Yeah, I've followed Clever Qazi's tutorial. Yes, maybe this might be the problem. Many people were complaining about the same.

Comment: This is not the problem guys please understand in the tutorial qazi only mentioned one parameter which he received only on the NETFLIX ORIGINALS and only plays videos which are in the NETFLIX ORIGINALS Row.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming becouse TMDB has not added ids for some videos if you want to play all video you just need need to change the genres of the Netflix Original Video from the path in request.js folder where you wrote your path becouse Netflix originals Videos has not linked with ids on TMDB.